# .gitattributes and normalizing line-endings: changed files still there

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes

I am confused with .gitattributes behavior.

Following the [article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) about normalizing line-endings, I have done following steps:

- created .gitattiributes with `* text=auto`
- on my **dev Windows machine** I have `core.autocrlf = true`
- on my **build Linux machine** I have `core.autocrlf = input`
- I have performed line-endings normalization on my dev machine running `git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard && git add . && git commit -m "normalized" && git push develop origin/develop`.

Last step according to my thoughts, should in the end push all text files with LF endings to repository and since that moment all my commits and chechouts will not be bothered with line-endings collisions on whatever platforms.

But when I have cloned the repo on my **build Linux** machine I immediately got a bunch of files marked as changed. If in the working copy on build machine I change .gitattributes line to `# * text=auto` (commented), everything becomes fine.

Why is that and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you seem to have to order of the commands mixed up: "git reset --hard" should come last, otherwise, I don't see that git add will actually add anything to the index...